# ALAssetsLibrary custom location services permission alert iPhone

Tags: iphone, alassetslibrary

I am using `ALAssetsLibrary` for accessing photos in my app and when apps first trying to access photos it asks for permissions for location services. I want to give custom message for that alert like App would like to access your photos instead location services.

I have search a lot on google and as well on stack overflow and I found solutions after user denied permissions for location services but not for custom message I have seen this in many apps like InstaCollage, Pic Jointer etc.

[image: Pic Jointer Alert Image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't (as you no doubt saw in your searches). That is a System message and you can't override it or avoid it. In other words: no means no.

Comment: the Pic Jointer app shows the above stated alert in the image when we want to fetch the photos for the first time not system generated so is there any way to show alternate alert like above image.

Comment: @robin.cssoft - that is a System message. There isn't any way around that. It is a security thing because `ALAssets` may contain location data. If the user denies access then you can't access it. You can ask the user in advance - before you try to access the library - and then do something based on that but again: no means no.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in iOS 6 you can add a custom text to the alert dialog (to specify what you are doing with the data etc.) To set this description text add the

```
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
```

key to Info.plist and set the value to the text you want to display.

From the developer documentation:

*NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription (String - iOS) describes the reason that the app accesses the user’s photo library. When the system prompts the user to allow access, this string is displayed as part of the dialog box.
This key is supported in iOS 6.0 and later.*

Comment: Just for clarification, since raw key names are not shown by default, the 'friendly' key text is: "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description". Calendars, Contacts, Locations, and Reminders also start with "Privacy - ..."

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing..

Just check your application Location service settings while your application loads and display your custom message

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

-(void)showAlertForLocationServiceEnabled{


    BOOL locationAllowed = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];

    if (locationAllowed == NO) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Service Disabled!!!" 
                                                        message:@"Location Services is required for this application. Please enable Location Services" 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    } 
}
```

or

```
-(void)checkAndNotifyLocationServiceAvailable{

    if (! ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) || ( [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)){

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Service Disabled!!!" message:@"Location Services is required for this application. Please enable Location Services" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
        [alert show];


    }

}
```